# Incorrect syntax near 'Name'

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I getting errors:

> Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Name'.

Please help to get from this.

I also added scalar to the names (`@`) but I am not getting anything.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlConnection con;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DELL_LAPTOP\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into newproj (Name,Designation,Gender,Age,Address,Date,Staff Name,Shift,ST,ET,Hours) Values (@Name,@Designation,@Gender,@Age,@Address,@Date,@Staff Name,@Shift,@ST,@ET,@Hours)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", textBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Designation", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString ());
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", textBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add ("@Staff Name", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add ("@Shift", comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ST", textBox7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ET", textBox8.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Hours", textBox6.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't include "nvarchar" anywhere... although I suspect you need to either escape or change `@Staff Name` to `@[Staff Name]` or `@StaffName`.

Comment: You can't have "Staff Name" because of the space. Try using "StaffName" or "Staff_Name" instead. (Obviously you will need to alter the database to match this)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is near this `Name`:

```
Insert Into newproj (Name,Designation,Gender,Age,Address,Date,Staff Name,Shift,ST,ET,Hours) Values
--                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Since the identifier contains spaces, you need to enclose it in square brackets, like this:

```
Insert Into newproj (Name,Designation,Gender,Age,Address,Date,[Staff Name],Shift,ST,ET,Hours) Values
```

Same goes for the `@Staff Name` parameter: since you own its name, you would be better off changing it to something without space.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use spaces in parameter names.

Change `@Staff Name` to `@StaffName`